# Compare nth elements of multiple lists

Tags: python

I have two tuples(they can be lists too) with elements that are related. An example is below:

```
as = (a0, a1, a2, a3, a4)
bs = (b0, b1, b2, b3, b4)
```

Elements at the same index are considered together: 'a0' is related to 'b0', and 'a1' is related to 'b1' etc

If 'a0' is not zero, then 'b0' must not be zero, and vice versa.

How do I test this condition for all the elements in these two tuples so the same is true for related pairs `(a1, b1)`, `(a2, b2)` etc?

Comment: "cannot be zero" or *must* not be zero? Do you need to check `a` against `a1` and so on?

Comment: Can't you just chain the operators? Do an if test on `not(x == y == 0)`

Comment: What should `a1` be changed to if `a1 == 0 and a != 0`? `a`?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Can you provide some sample input and desired output?

Comment: "How do I do this for all the elements" <- How do I do WHAT?

Comment: Sorry gents, I thought that this was pretty clear. If element 'a' is not zero, then element 'a1' (which is related to element 'a') can also not be zero. Similarly, if element 'a1' is not zero, then element 'a' cannot be zero. I want to do this for all the elements in these two tuples, that is why I said the elements are related.

Comment: I think the thing that is unclear to people is what you want to happen when there's a mismatch. I wrote my answer assuming you simply wanted to detect if there was a problem or not, and what happened after that is none of our business. Closing the question to me shows a lack of imagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this elegently with an izip

```
from itertools import izip

...

for a, b in izip(tuple1, tuple2):
    if not check(a, b)
        return False
return True

# or as a one-liner
all(check(a, b) for (a, b) in izip(tuple1, tuple2))
```

`check` can be implemented as follows (n.b. I have taken the spec literally and compared to zero rather than use python truthyness):

```
def check(a, b):
    return (a == 0) != (b == 0)
```

Or if you know that the tuple only contains numeric data you can simplify to:

```
def check(a, b):
    return bool(a) != bool(b)
```

But bear in mind that [python truth testing can catch beginners out.](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7.7/library/stdtypes.html#index-2)

The docs for [izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)

Comment: Sure, and then elem is a tuple of all the nth elements of the iterators passed to izip.

Comment: Thanks very much Robbie. This is definitely very close to what I am looking for. Marvelous!!

Comment: Thanks, don't forget to upvote and select an answer if you found it helpful!

Comment: Thanks Robbie, I have upvoted it. You have helped me tremendously.

Comment: Apparently Robbie, because I have just signed up today, I am being prevented from upvoting because my reputation here is still minimal. I need 15 reputation and I don't have that. Arggh. Anyway, your answer was the most helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
ok = all((a and b) or (not a and not b) for a,b in zip(tuple1,tuple2))
```

This uses `zip` to associate the values from both tuples, you get them back as a pair when you iterate the result.

Each pair is evaluated to see if they're both non-zero (True) or zero (False).

`all` is used to combine all of the results; if any pair returns `False` then the result is `False`.

Comment: Thanks Mark but I don't understand your code. Is zip a function in python?

Comment: I did not downvote it, I just said I don't understand it. Wanted to know if zip is a function in python?

Comment: @user3726586, yes both `zip` and `all` are built in functions.

Comment: @user3726586 I wasn't accusing you (or anybody else in particular) of being the downvoter. Just curious as to what's going on.

Comment: +1 - I don't see what is wrong with this answer.  I would have put the same thing, except I probably would have done `ok = all(bool(a) == bool(b) for a,b in zip(tuple1, tuple2))`.  But the same concept applies.

Comment: I have just seen that this works too Mark. Thanks a lot. It was not you, it was me. New to some of these Python functions.